# Calculating points on an arc

Tags: geometry

As part of a parametric component I'm building, I need know how to calculate 'Y' on the attached image.
I know 'R' - which is a variable, and 'x' - a constant. bashing my head on this for hours, appreciate any assistance.[Finding Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FIhh.jpg)

Comment: Tell me what you tried when you were “bashing your head for hours. This may leave some insight. This is a review:try to [use this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know
$$
x^2 + y^2 = R^2
$$
so
$$
y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}.
$$

Comment: my math is shocking, I'd used / instead of - ! Thanks :)